# The difference between a handle decomposition and a CW decomposition

Tags: morse-theory, differential-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Let $M$ be a compact finite-dimensional smooth manifold. I have a question about the relationship between the statements that a Morse function induces a [handle decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handle_decomposition) for $M$, and that it induces a [CW decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex) for $M$.

#### A Morse function induces a handle decomposition

Denote by $X(M;f;s)$ the manifold $M$ with an $s$--handle attached by $f\colon\,(\partial D^s)\times D^{n-s}\to M$.

> **Theorem**: Let f be a $C^\infty$ function on $M$ with no critical points on $f^{-1}[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ except $k$ nondegenerate ones on $f^{-1}(0)$, all of index $s$. Then $f^{-1}[-\infty,\epsilon]$ is diffeomorphic to $X(f^{-1}[-\infty,-\epsilon];f_1,\ldots,f_k;s)$ (for suitable f<sub>i</sub>).

**Historical note**: This was stated by Smale in 1961, with proof outline. Milnor's *Morse Theory*, Theorem 3.2 states and proves a weaker, homotopy version of the theorem, where there is only one handle in play. I asked about a proof of this theorem in [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70248/searching-for-an-unabridged-proof-of-the-basic-theorem-of-morse-theory), and it turned out that the first complete proof appeared in [Palais](https://web.archive.org/web/20060907050220/http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~getzler/Morse/palais.pdf), simplified lated by Fukui [Math. Sem. Notes Kobe Univ. 3 (1975), no. 1, paper no. X, pp. 1-4]. There's an alternative proof given in Appendix C to Madsen-Tornehave.

**Discussion**: Roughly, the theorem states that passing a critical point of a Morse function corresponds to attaching a handle. Thus, a Morse function induces a handle decomposition for $M$.

#### A Morse function induces a CW decomposition

Let $f$ be a Morse function on $M$. Choosing a complete Riemannian metric on $M$ determines a stratification of $M$ into cells $D(p)$ (the unstable (descending) manifold for a critical point $p$ of $f$) in which two points lie in the same stratum if they are on the same unstable manifold. Each $D(p)$ is homeomorphic to an open cell, but the closure $\overline{D(p)}$ can be complicated.

> **Theorem**: The union of compactified unstable manifolds $\bigcup \overline{D(p)}$  gives a CW decomposition of $M$ that is homeomorphic to $M$.

**Historical note**: A nice discussion of this theorem may be found in Bott's excellent [Morse Theorem Indomitable](http://www.springerlink.com/content/b53n6p7813u5452p/fulltext.pdf), page 104. Milnor's *Morse Theory* derives a homotopy version of this statement (Theorem 3.5) from the homotopy version of the statement that a Morse function induces a handle decomposition (Theorem 3.2). The theorem seems to have been first proven by [Kalmbach](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/on-some-results-in-morse-theory/C18F9616CB12F4586C44060FCC608975), and was recently strengthened to give the explicit characteristic maps by [Lizhen Qin](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.2838) (understanding his papers is the motivation for my question).

---

The two statements given above look to me as though they should be very similar, especially since the homotopy version of the second follows directly from the homotopy version for the first in Milnor's book. But briefly searching through the literature makes it seem that they are virtually independant- papers proving one aren't even cited in papers proving the other, and the proofs look to me to be entirely unconnected. I don't understand why, probably because I'm having difficulty breaking free from the intuitive picture of the proof in Milnor's book, which works fine up to homotopy.

> **Question**: Can you give an example, or intuition, for a case in which one of the above theorems is difficult but the other is easy? Is there an example for a compact finite-dimensional manifold with a Morse function such that the handlebody decomposition can be read straight off the Morse function, but the reading off the CW decomposition takes substantial extra work? Or the converse?
> Stated differently, where does the "up to homotopy proof" on page 23 of Milnor conceptually collapse when we are working up to diffeomorphism instead of up to homotopy?

Comment: In the 2nd highlighted theorem you quote, shouldn't "that is diffeomorphic to $M$' be erased?  Stating that it's a CW-decomposition of $M$ should be enough.  CW-complexes don't have smooth structures so it's not clear what the latter part means. 

Comment: I suppose I view the CW-structure on $M$ to be the less natural thing.  To construct an explicit CW-decomposition on $M$ you either have to do something like modify the flow-lines for the gradient of $f$, or do some kind of blow-up procedure to turn the (naturally discontinuous) cellular attaching maps into continuous maps.  Neither option is particularly pleasant.  The handle decomposition is rather natural provided $f$ has some modest restrictions on it.  But to answer your question it depends on what "reading off" means.  There's substantially less information in a CW-decomposition so...

Comment: generally that takes less effort to generate, especially if all you care about is the homotopy-equivalent CW-complex, rather than putting the structure on $M$ itself.   

Comment: Note that a handle decomposition can be turned around, in a way that corresponds to replacing $f$ by $-f$. But the same is not true for a CW structure up to homotopy. 

Comment: The second Theorem is true for generic Riemannian metric only. The standard 2-torus in $R^3$, height function and the standard induced metric is a counterexamlpe (the boundary of upper 1-cell does not belong to the 0-cell). So in general we have only decomposition into disjoint union of balls, not CW-structure.

Comment: Ryan: typo corrected

Comment: @ Petya: the example you gave is the standard exampple of a Morse flow that violates  the Morse-Smale condition. The CW-decomposition is intimately to the flow.  Change the metric, you change the flow. Also, Morse-Smale  condition is not enough. You need some conditions  on the spectra of the Hessians. These spectra change when you change the metric,  while    maintaining the   Morse-Smale transversality.

Comment: @Liviu I just mention that the original statement is wrong, do you agree with that?

Comment: @ Petya. Yes.  Your example is a counterexample to the 2nd Theorem as stated. It needs two  extra assumptions to be true: Morse-Smale + a little bit more.

Comment: @Liviu: I am confused by "a little bit more". My understanding is that the paper by Qin linked to in the question (Theorem B in that paper to be precise) shows that the unstable manifolds give a CW decomposition assuming only the Morse-Smale condition.

Comment: He assumes that near a critical point the metric is flat and the  function $f$ has the form $f(x)=\pm x_1^2\pm x_2^2\pm \cdots \pm x_n^2$.

Comment: @Liviu: It seems to me that he doesn't. X is a gradient like vector field for the function and is only required to be the gradient with respect to some metric near the critical points (see Definition 2.1).

Comment: He refers to these assumptions as local triviality.   Read the first paragraph in section 3, top page 10  of his paper http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/1012.3643

Comment: Also read the two paragraphs immediately   following the statement of Theorem 3.5, page 13 of his paper http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/1012.3643

Comment: I understand that the older paper you link to requires the metric to be standard near the critical points. But my understanding is that the more recent paper linked to in the question (front.math.ucdavis.edu/1102.2838) is precisely meant to address the case of an arbitrary metric. Qin says so explicitly in the abstract.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18573/discussion-between-liviu-nicolaescu-and-gustavo-granja).

Comment: @GustavoGranja here's an updated link for that paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.2838, Qin's _An application of topological equivalence to Morse theory_ (published as https://doi.org/10.1007/s11784-020-00843-z)

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu here's an updated link for the paper, _On Moduli Spaces and CW Structures Arising from Morse Theory On Hilbert Manifolds_ by Lizhen Qin, linked in your two comments: https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.3643 (published as https://doi.org/10.1142/S1793525310000409)

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken, but the article can be found at [doi:10.1007/BF02698544](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02698544), [Numdam](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=PMIHES_1988__68__99_0), or [EuDML](https://eudml.org/doc/104046) ([Zbl 0685.58009](https://zbmath.org/0685.58009)).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The second of  the theorems you quoted is **considerably** harder to prove.  The gist  of the proof is as follows. Consider the closure $\overline{D(p)}$ of $D(p)$ in $M$. Then  Lizhen Qin proves that it admits a resolution in the sense of  semi-algebraic geometry. More precisely he constructs a  compact space $\widehat{D(p)}$ and a   continuous surjective  map   $\pi: \widehat{D(p)}\to\overline{D(p)}$ with  the following properties.

$\bullet$  The space $\widehat{D(p)}$ is homeomorphic to a closed ball of dimension equal to the Morse index of $p$.

$\bullet$ The restriction of $\pi$ to the interior of $\widehat{D(p)}$ induces a *homeomorphism* onto $D(p)$.

The theorem **requires that the gradient flow satisfy the  Morse-Smale transversality condition** wheras no such requirement is needed for the  handle decomposition theorem. Moreover, the result  is **very sensitive to the behavior of the gradient flow  near the critical  points**.    In  such a region the flow  is a linear flow given by a symmetric matrix, the Hessian of $f$ at that particular point. If the eigenvalues are $\pm 1$ things are fine.  For different eigenvalues  things can go horribly wrong.

In  Chap. 8 of my paper  [Tame flows](http://www.nd.edu/%7Elnicolae/tameflow.pdf)  I show  that under appropriate conditions  on the eigenvalues of the Hessians at the critical points the Morse-Smale  condition is equivalent  to the  requirement that the stratification by unstable manifolds be a Whitney  regular  stratification. Moreover I give    examples and pictures describing  how  the  Whitney regularity  is destroyed    if the spectra of the Hessians  do not satisfy those  constraints.

Another very good reference for these topics is Burghelea-Friedlander-Kappeler survey  [arXiv: 1101.0778](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.0778). Burghelea has  an alternate and much simpler argument for Lizhen Qin's result, and the paper arXiv: 1101.0778 is much more readable than Qin's.

In the shameless-plug department, I ought to mention  the recent 2nd edition of my book An Invitation to Morse Theory. In Chapter 4 I discuss at length these issues without the tameness assumption.

Comment: Liviu, are you sure that Burghelea et. al. produce the CW decomposition in the reference you cited? I could not find it mentioned there. In fact, I did a search of the file for the term "CW" and it is not to be found there. Also, my impression was that Burghelea and company only handle the case of a metric which is standard near the critical point set.

Comment: It's not in their paper, I agree. In that paper they produce the compact space $\widehat{D}(p)$  and the projection $\pi$  so that the preimage of $D(p)$  in $\widehat{D(p)}$ is open dense.    Their construction of $\widehat{D(p)}$ is identical to Qin's but the presentation is  cleaner.  As Qin mentions in  his paper these facts alone imply immediately  (via some  nontrivial results in topology) that $\widehat{D}(p)$ is  topological disk.     Qin gives an alternate proof that avoids   these topological results.   I find this part of his proof hard to diggest.

Comment: Thanks Liviu. I presume that you mean "some nontrivial results in topology" refers to the $h$-cobordism theorem (or maybe the Poincare conjecture). Lizhen wanted to avoid using such a big weapon, so he found an alternative proof--a proof which uses more elementary tools.

Comment: Yep. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 4):

Another reference I would like to mention is

Sharko, V.V. Functions on manifolds, Translations of Mathematical
  Monographs, Volume 131.  American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI (1993).
Algebraic and topological aspects, Translated from the Russian by V.
  V. Minachin.

He really does use some aspects of the crossed complex related to the handlebody decomposition, rather than the CW-filtration. We have suggested this as a line of possible development in our book "Nonabelian algebraic topology: filtered spaces, crossed complexes, cubical homotopy groupoids" (EMS Tract 15, 2011) since we work there with filtered spaces, and you get such from a Morse function on a manifold. I feel there is more to do there, using for example the tensor product technology explained in our book. This tensor product does reflect the usual cell decomposition of the product $E^m \times E^n$, $m,n \geqslant 0$, where $E^m, E^n$ have cell decompositions with 3 cells.

Comment: This sounds very interesting!